# Sorting objects in Rego, based on multiple attributes

Tags: sorting, opa, rego

I'm trying to write some code in OPA Rego to sort a collection of objects based on the value of multiple attributes. I start with the objects in a dictionary as below and I'd like to sort the objects inside and return their relative ids.
So having the dictionary

```
dict = { 
    "1": {"name": "ccc", "foo": "4"},
    "2": {"name": "aaa", "foo": "1"},
    "3": {"name": "bbb", "foo": "6"},
    "4": {"name": "eee", "foo": "5"},
    "5": {"name": "eee", "foo": "2"},
    "6": {"name": "ddd", "foo": "3"} 
}
```

sorting first by **name** and then by **foo** I would expect to return `[ 2 3 1 6 5 4]`
Notice that for ids 4 and 5 the objects have the same *name*, so the order should be decided by *foo*

My first attempt is

```
_sorted = res{ 
    orderBy = ["name", "foo"]
    sorted1 = sort([ x | x := dict[_][orderBy[0]] ])
    res = [id | sorted1[_] == dict[id][orderBy[0]] ]
}
```

but this approach has problems when there are objects with the same *name*, therefore the following result  `"_sorted": ["2","3","1","6",**"4","5","4","5"**]`

The second attempt was using sets instead, which solves the duplication issue

```
_sorted = res{ 
    orderBy = ["name", "foo"]
    sorted1 = { x | x := dict[_][orderBy[0]] }
    res = [id | sorted1[_] == dict[id][orderBy[0]] ]
}
```

but I don't know how to make it work with sorting on 2 attributes - last attempt

```
_sorted = res{ 
    orderBy = ["name", "foo"]
    sorted1 = { x | x := dict[_][orderBy[0]] }
    sorted2 = { x | x := dict[_][orderBy[1]] }
    res = [id | sorted1[_] == dict[id][orderBy[0]]; sorted2[_] == dict[sid][orderBy[1]] ]
}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key to sorting declaratively is to calculate the rank of each element, and then build an array accordingly.

I've given your example a go here: [playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/lVQeDgj9ff)

```
rank(x, k, coll) := count(smaller) {
  smaller := { y | some y in coll; y[k] <= x[k] }
}

sorted(k, coll) := { r: sorted_("foo", es) |
    some r in numbers.range(1, count(coll))
    es := { e | some e in coll; r == rank(e, k, coll) }
}

# same as sorted, without the inner sorted_ call
sorted_(k, coll) := { r: es |
    some r in numbers.range(1, count(coll))
    es := { e | some e in coll; r == rank(e, k, coll) }
}

result := [ x | x := sorted("name", dict)[_][_][_] ]
```

It is not generic in the `orderBy` array -- `name` and `foo` are hardcoded there.

I think it might be cool to add a new built-in function: `sort_by(any<array<object>, set<object>) -> array<object>`